# QtDesigner layout confusion

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qmainwindow

I've been playing around with QtDesigner for some time now, but I can't find a real solution for my desired layout.

Here's what I'm aiming for, kind of an Eclipse RCP-like layout:

[image]

Five drag&dropable widgets which can be rearranged and whatnot (so Dockwidgets). Thats what happend in above screenshot, I just pulled five Dockwidgets into the Mainwindow and populated them with Items. But the problem is that Dockwidgets only snap to the edges of the Mainwindow, and leave space to CentralWidget, which you see in the middle. Is there some way to add a containing widget to the center and fill it with DockWidgets?

On a side note: Is it feasable to do something like this in the Designer? I see why this program is useful, as GUIs can be set up and changed extremly fast, but I feel like stripped of any power on the exact look. I'm kinda itching to (attempt to) write the GUI by hand, because I'm feeling so powerless! :-)

P.S.:How can the screenshot be scaled? It seems overly huge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no. As it says in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdockwidget.html)

> Dock windows are secondary windows placed in the dock widget area around the central widget in a QMainWindow.